# Filter a model's attributes before outputting as json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, html-helper

I need to output my model as json and everything is going fine. However, some of the attributes need to be 'beautified' by filtering them through some helper methods, such as `number_to_human_size`. How would I go about doing this?

In other words, say that I have an attribute named `bytes` and I want to pass it through `number_to_human_size` and have *that* result be output to json.

I would also like to 'trim' what gets output as json if that's possible, since I only need some of the attributes. Is this possible? Can someone please give me an example? I would really appreciate it.

Preliminary search results hint at something regarding `as_json`, but I can't find a tangible example pertaining to my situation. If this is really the solution, I would really appreciate an example.

**Research**: It seems I can use `to_json`'s options to explicitly state which attributes I want, but I'm still in need of figuring out how to 'beautify' or 'filter' certain attributes by passing them through a helper before they're output as json.

Would I create a partial for a single json model, so _model.json.erb, and then create another one for the action I'm using, and within that simply render the partial with the collection of objects? Seems like a bunch of hoops to jump through. I'm wondering if there's a more direct/raw way of altering the json representation of a model.

Comment: you are displaying your json?  Like in a view? If so,  how come?

Comment: Sorry if that's what you inferred. No, I'm not. I'm basically trying to alter the way my model gets turned into a json object. I've figured out >a< way to do it so far, I'll post it up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your model can override the `as_json` method, which Rails uses when rendering json:

```
# class.rb
include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  def as_json(options={})
    { :state => state, # just use the attribute when no helper is needed
      :downloaded => number_to_human_size(downloaded)
    }
  end
end
```

Now you can call `render :json` in the controller:

```
@items = Item.all
# ... etc ...
format.json { render :json => @items }
```

Rails will call `Item.as_json` for each member of @items and return a JSON-encoded array.

Comment: This seems like a more natural, or rather, the conventional way of doing what I did in my answer. I will adapt it to your solution and see how it goes.

Comment: It was a drop-in modification. I just had to move my hash building code to as_json and everything continues to work as expected. I do notice the options parameter, does this mean I can render different 'versions' of the object given a parameter? So for example, if I want a 'bare' object with only the bare minimum, I can render that, otherwise it renders the complete thing, can I do that? I'd just check to see if the option exists and if it's set to something right, but how would I pass that option when I'm actually rendering it?

Comment: I take it I would simply pass the options to an explicit call to as_json right? So render :son => @items.as_json(:bare => true). Also, should I be calling super in any way? How?

Comment: The `options` are there so you can do `.to_json(:only=>:name)` and so on, as described in the API (http://api.rubyonrails.org/ -- see ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON. I don't see why you'd need to do that, or need to call `super`, unless you need to handle those cases. Calling super is just the method `super`, or `super(my_options)` if you need to alter the options.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out ***a*** solution to this problem, but I don't know if it's the best. I would appreciate insight.

```
@items = Item.all

@response = []

@items.each do |item|
  @response << {
      :state => item.state,
      :lock_status => item.lock_status,
      :downloaded => ActionController::Base.helpers.number_to_human_size(item.downloaded),
      :uploaded => ActionController::Base.helpers.number_to_human_size(item.uploaded),
      :percent_complete => item.percent_complete,
      :down_rate => ActionController::Base.helpers.number_to_human_size(item.down_rate),
      :up_rate => ActionController::Base.helpers.number_to_human_size(item.up_rate),
      :eta => item.eta
  }
end

respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render :json => @response }
end
```

Basically I construct a hash on the fly with the values I want and then render *that* instead. It's working, but like I said, I'm not sure if it's the best way.