# Hiding Rails Model Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a controller for an API that looks like this:

```
def index
  respond_to   do |format|
    format.json  { render :json => @groups.to_json(:only => [:id, :name, :description, :created_at, :updated_at])}
  end
end

def show
  respond_to   do |format|
    format.json  { render :json => @group.to_json(:only => [:id, :name, :description, :created_at, :updated_at]) }
  end
end

# @todo add store to item
def create
  if @group.save
    render :json => @group.to_json(:only => [:id, :name, :description, :created_at, :updated_at])
  else
    render :status => 406
  end
end

def update
  if @group.update_attributes(params[:group])
    render :json => @group.to_json(:only => [:id, :name, :description, :created_at, :updated_at])
  else
    render :status => 406
  end
end

def destroy
  @group.destroy
  render :text => ""
end
```

As you can see, I'm repeating my self a lot. I'd love to make these (and only these) attributes available by way of the model, but couldn't find a fitting solution. Is there anything to protect attributes from mass writing? Or do I possibly mean mass reading?

As noted in comments below I want to have a model with attributes, `name` and `i_am_private`. When I render that model as json - `render :json => @model` - I want only `name` to show up.

Ruby 1.8.7
Rails 3

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of 
[Filter a model's attributes before outputting as json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550925/filter-a-models-attributes-before-outputting-as-json)

Comment: Also you will find this useful: http://jonathanjulian.com/2010/04/rails-to_json-or-as_json/ and

Comment: It definitely looks to be. I'm going to try to stop asking questions so late at night.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about overriding as_json method in your Group model?

```
class Group < ActiveRecord:Base
  ...
  def as_json(options={})
    {
      :id => id,
      :name => name,
      :description => description,
      :created_at => created_at,
      :updated_at => updated_at
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: gahhh. overrides! why to freakin simple. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent mass assignment, add the following to your model:

```
  attr_accessible :attr1, :attr2, :attr3
```

where attr1, attr2, attr3 and so on are the attributes you want to allow for mass assignment, the rest of the attributes for that model **will not** be allowed for mass assignment.

Comment: That projects against mass assignment, but not mass writing. So if I have `private_attr` that I don't want to show up when using `render :json => @object`, `attr_accessable :private_attr` doesn't work.