# How can I convert MySQL latitude / longitude data to JSON using Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide on this question: How can I use Ruby on Rails to create a JSON object from the "latitude" and "longitude" data in my MySQL table, "Locations"?

My ultimate goal is to create a Google Map with multiple markers pulled from a MySQL database. I know that I can do this through PHP and the Google tutorial (https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3), but I'm not strong in PHP and am looking for a shorter way to do it through Rails.

I have tried this other tutorial (http://mokisystemsblog.blogspot.com/2013/04/add-markers-to-google-map-with-ruby-on.html), and here is my code for my controller:

```
    class MapallController < ApplicationController
      # GET /mapall
      # GET /mapall.xml
      # GET /mapall.js

      def index
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html do
            @locations = Location.find(:all)
          end
          format.xml  { render :xml => @locations }
          format.js do
            ne = params[:ne].split(',').collect{|e|e.to_f}  
            sw = params[:sw].split(',').collect{|e|e.to_f}
            @locations = Location.find(:all, :limit => 100, :bounds => [sw, ne])
            render :json => @locations.to_json
          end
        end
      end
    end
```

However, when I visit www.example.com/mapall.js, I get an error code. I expect that this link would give me the complete set of results from my database.

Again, I appreciate your advice and patience as I learn this process!

**EDIT 1 - ERROR CODE**

Below is the log for what happens when I visit example.com/mapall, example.com/mapall.js, and example.com/mapall.xml. When I visit example.com/mapall, I expect a Google Map that renders all of my locations from the MySQL database. Barring that, I expected to see the lat / long data when I visited mapall.js. From the log below, I'm guessing the reason that I'm getting a 404 is that there is no route to mapall.js in my routes file. Is the solution to create a route to the routes file, and if so, how should that read?

Thanks again for your help!

```
    Processing MapallController#index (for IP at DATE TIME) [GET]
    Rendering template within layouts/mapall
    Rendering mapall/index
    Completed in 779ms (View: 7, DB: 100) | 200 OK [http://example.com/mapall]

    Processing ApplicationController#index (for IP at DATE TIME) [GET]

    ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/mapall.js" with {:method=>:get}):
    /phusion_passenger ERROR INFO
    Rendering /home/example/web/current/public/404.html (404 Not Found)

    Processing ApplicationController#index (for IP at DATE TIME) [GET]

    ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/mapall.xml" with {:method=>:get}):
    /phusion_passenger ERROR INFO
    Rendering /home/example/web/current/public/404.html (404 Not Found)
```

**EDIT 2 - New Controller**

Thanks to @kyllo's feedback, I've been able to update the controller so that I can get ALL of my location data to appear at http://example.com/mapall.js. Only one step left: getting just the nickname, latitude, and longitude fields to appear. The below shows ALL of the data. How should I change this to show only the nickname, latitude, and longitudinal fields?

```
    class MapallController < ApplicationController
    # GET /mapall
    # GET /mapall.xml
    # GET /mapall.js

    def index
    respond_to do |format|
@masterlocation = Masterlocation.find(:all)
    format.html do
    end
    format.xml  { render :xml => @masterlocation }
    format.js do
    @masterlocation = Masterlocation.find(:all)
    render :json => @masterlocation.to_json
    end
    end
    end
    end
```

Comment: Can you not look at the logs and see the stack trace? Or run this in development mode and see the actual exception?

Comment: Douglas, thanks for your comment. I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly, but I looked at the www.example.com/mapall page in Firebug and couldn't find an exception. My javascript reads: `<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?MYAPIV2CODE" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript">THE CODE FROM THE MAPS.JS EXAMPLE</script>` but the JSON information doesn't seem to have come through.

Comment: you'll need to provide the actual error -- check in log/development.log

Comment: Thanks, Jesse and Douglas. I've posted the errors in my updated question. I appreciate your feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few problems here.

Yes, you are getting a "no route matches" error so you need a route in routes.rb similar to this, so that you can access `:format` as a parameter to respond to:

`match 'mapall.:format'`

Then in your controller, you have the following:

```
def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html do
        @locations = Location.find(:all)
      end
      format.xml  { render :xml => @locations }
      format.js do
        ne = params[:ne].split(',').collect{|e|e.to_f}  
        sw = params[:sw].split(',').collect{|e|e.to_f}
        @locations = Location.find(:all, :limit => 100, :bounds => [sw, ne])
        render :json => @locations.to_json
      end
    end
  end
```

Your `@locations = Location.find(:all)` needs to be outside of the `format.html do` block, otherwise @locations is undefined inside of your `format.xml` block and you will get an error.

`format.js do` will allow your user to access the JSON API by visiting `http:/www.example.com/mapall.js`. If you use `format.json do` then they can access it at `http:/www.example.com/mapall.json`. The choice is yours.

Hope that helps to put you on the right track!

Comment: Kyllo, Thanks so much for your comments! I've updated the question. I think with a little more info, I'll be able to finish off the project. Any additional help you can provide would be great!

Comment: To limit the fields that will be displayed when your model is accessed as XML or JSON, you need to override the as_json and to_xml methods in your model code. See these threads: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348735/hiding-rails-model-attributes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550925/filter-a-models-attributes-before-outputting-as-json

Comment: Kyllo, I am traveling until the weekend but will try this out and get back to you. Thanks for your continued support.

Comment: My actual solution was to filter the data within the controller. I did something like what was included in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348735/hiding-rails-model-attributes: 
`respond_to   do |format|
    format.json  { render :json => @groups.to_json(:only => [:id, :name, :description, :created_at, :updated_at])}
  end
end`